# combine 8 tables into 1

Tags: r, excel, powerbi

I've got 8 diffrent tables that looks like this

```
 date/time        v    t    o    ID
3-4-2017 13:15   10    1    8    X
3-4-2017 13:30   15    0    6    X
3-4-2017 13:45   12    0    2    X

 date/time        v    t    o    ID
3-4-2017 13:15   10    1    8    Y
3-4-2017 13:30   15    0    6    Y
3-4-2017 13:45   12    0    2    Y
```

I want to visualize in Power BI on a map the ID states wher it should be maped. But for this visualisation my data should look like this.

```
date/time        v    t    o    ID
3-4-2017 13:15   10    1    8    X
3-4-2017 13:15   10    1    8    Y
3-4-2017 13:30   15    0    6    X
3-4-2017 13:30   15    0    6    Y
3-4-2017 13:45   12    0    2    X
3-4-2017 13:45   12    0    2    Y
```

I have tested this on a small part but have to be able to do this on 3 to 4 years. I'd rather do this in Excel or BI itself but R is a option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, an efficient way to bind multiple data frames sharing same columns, is `dplyr::bind_rows()`. For instance for 3 tables:

```
bind_table <- bind_rows(table1, table2, table3)
```

Comment: Thanks it works I'll be used it in BI so if my colluge just refreshes the don't need to know R-code.

Answer (score 1):

Combining multiple identical files in the same folder together is functionality built into Power BI:

1. On the **Get Data** screen, select **Folder** and then **Connect**

[image: Folder]

2. Navigate to the folder with your files
3. Select **Combine & Edit** or **Combine & Load**.

[image: Combine]

You will need to edit if you have further transformations to do such *Use First Row As Headers* or filtering out other header rows from your data, but the work of combining the data in each file into a single dataset will be done for you.

[image: Final result of combining the 2 sample tables from the original question together]

Answer (score 0):

If these tables live in a database, and you can query them with your PowerBI tool, a simple UNION between queries will do the trick.

Example

```
select * from table1 
UNION
select * from table2
```

Comment: the example represents data from provider in excel file format(or csv, no other possibilities). And we haven't got it in a live database. If there is new data we place that in the correct file (in the example x or y) .    I rather do a uniuon in BI or in Excel because other people have to work with this and don't know R language.

Comment: To my knowledge, PowerBI can to take CSV files as a data source, then query those data sources with SQL, as described above. Whether this, or some other presentation form suits your use case best, really depends on your requirements though, and those indexing those requirements is beyond the scope of StackOverflow (the primary function of which is to get help solve specific coding challenges).